# 2 questions in one post. What to do?

Tags: discussion, questions

This question really has two questions in the same post: [What is the relationship between zone density and wealth?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110018/what-is-the-relationship-between-zone-density-and-wealth)

Just to be very clear, the two questions are
1. What is the relationship between high density and wealth?
2. How do I get high density industrial zones?

Additionally, question #2 might be better addressed by a more general question, "How do I increase zone density".

It seems like it would be better to have this question split up, but I'm not sure of what specific action I should take. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two extreme views we could consider:

- Make them ask two questions, and if they don't, close it or downvote it or leave a comment.
- Just answer it, it's their question and they believe them to be related.

The "right answer" is probably somewhere in between.

If the questions are similar or related enough that it's not really that much trouble to explain the concept that underpins them, then just answer it.  Sometimes you can look at a game mechanic or situation and have a couple of questions that make sense together, and that's OK.

If the questions are so different as to be completely unrelated, try leaving a friendly comment along the lines of "you've got two questions here, and they're really different enough that you might get better help or answers if you asked them separately."